# Loop For working too long

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two list of dicts: `prices_distincts`, `prices`.

They connect through `hash_brand_artnum`, both of them sorted by `hash_brand_artnum`
 I do not understand why loop works for so long:

1. If length of `prices_distincts` is 100,000 it works for `30 min`
2. But If length of `prices_distincts` is 10,000 it works for `10 sec`.

**Code:**

```
 prices_distincts = [{'hash_brand_artnum':1202},...,..]
 prices = [{'hash_brand_artnum':1202,'price':12.077},...,...]

 for prices_distinct in prices_distincts:
    for price in list(prices):            
        if prices_distinct['hash_brand_artnum'] == price['hash_brand_artnum']:

            print price['hash_brand_artnum']
            #print prices
            del prices[0]
        else:
            continue
```

I need to look for items with same prices.  Relation beatween prices_distincts and prices one to many. And group price with equal price['hash_brand_artnum']

Comment: it's working so long because your algorithm is O(N^2) and 100000 ^ 2 = 10000000000 and 10000 ^ 2 = 100000000.
So factor between two number is 100, and factor between 30 min and 10 sec ~100

Comment: @RomanPekar That should be an answer.

Comment: Those are not dicts, but list of dicts.

Answer (score 10):

it's working so long because your algorithm is O(N^2) and 100000 ^ 2 = 10000000000 and 10000 ^ 2 = 100000000. So factor between two number is 100, and factor between 30 min and 10 sec ~100.

**EDIT:** It's hard to say by your code and such a small amount of data, and I don't know what your task is, but I think that your dictionaries is not very useful.
May be try this:

```
>>> prices_distincts = [{'hash_brand_artnum':1202}, {'hash_brand_artnum':14}]
>>> prices = [{'hash_brand_artnum':1202, 'price':12.077}, {'hash_brand_artnum':14, 'price':15}]
# turning first list of dicts into simple list of numbers
>>> dist = [x['hash_brand_artnum'] for x in prices_distincts]
# turning second list of dicts into dict where number is a key and price is a value
>>> pr = {x['hash_brand_artnum']:x["price"] for x in prices}
```

not you can iterate throuth your number and get prices:

```
>>> for d in dist:
...     print d, pr[d]
```

Comment: Roman, please take a look at the last comment on [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973049/sql-query-to-select-distinct-rows-from-left-table-after-inner-join-to-the-right)

Answer (score 5):

As @RomanPekar mentioned, your algorithm is running slow because its complexity is `O(n^2)`. To fix it, you should write it as an `O(n)` algorithm:

```
import itertools as it

for price, prices_distinct in it.izip(prices, prices_distincts):
    if prices_distinct['hash_brand_artnum'] == price['hash_brand_artnum']:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. The question was "Why?"

Answer (score 0):

If prices grows more or less with prices_distincts, then if you multiply the size of  prices_distincts by 10, your original 10 seconds will be multiply by 10 then again by 10 (second for loop), and then by ~2 because of the "list(prices)" (that, by the way, should definitively be done out of the loop):

10sec*10*10*2 = 2000sec = 33min

This conversion is usually expensive.

```
 prices_distincts = [{'hash_brand_artnum':1202},...,..]
 prices = [{'hash_brand_artnum':1202,'price':12.077},...,...]
 list_prices = list(prices)

 for prices_distinct in prices_distincts:
    for price in list_prices:            
        if prices_distinct['hash_brand_artnum'] == price['hash_brand_artnum']:

            print price['hash_brand_artnum']
            #print prices
            del prices[0]
        else:
            continue
```