# SQL query to select distinct rows from left table after inner join to the right table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, database-design, inner-join

I have two MySQL tables. This is first one [products] (PRIMARY = id):

```
[id] | title | description
```

and this is the second [sizes] (PRIMARY = id & size):

```
[id] | [size]
```

`size` can only have values from `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

I have a PHP array which has the size values. I reshape it to a comma-separated values string like this:

```
$size_list = implode(",", $sizes);
```

For those who are not familiar with PHP, the above code will generate an string like this: "1,4,5" and then query the database like this:

```
$query = "SELECT t1.id,t1.title,t1.description,t2.size FROM products t1 INNER JOIN sizes t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHERE size IN(".$size_list .")";
```

But this query replicates the products for each size they have in the sizes table.
I want to:

**Return records from products table which have at least one available size in sizes table, without duplicate**

and of course

**want those sizes in a variable to show to the client**

---

For example:

Products:

```
1 | product1 | description1
2 | product2 | description2
3 | product3 | description3
4 | product4 | description4
```

Sizes:

```
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 4
1 | 5
2 | 1
2 | 5
```

Given `$sizes_list="1,2"`, what I want as output is:

```
1 | product1 | description1 | 1,2,4,5
2 | product2 | description2 | 1,5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should be like:

```
$query = "
    select t1.id, t1.title, t1.description, group_concat(t2.size SEPARATOR ",") as sizes
    from products as t1
       inner join sizes as t2 on t1.id=t2.id
    where t1.id in (select t3.id from sizes as t3 where t3.size in (".$size_list .")
    group by t1.id, t1.title, t1.description
"
```

A bit of explanation. When you join two tables, you get all rows from table `sizes` for all `id` from table `products`, so id = 1 joined with four records and id = 2 joined with two records. So you have to aggregate this numbers into one record.

Comment: OMG, I think there is something wrong with this query I did not mention. I think `it does not list all the sizes for the product. It does just the sizes that are in $size_list`. am I wrong Roman?

Comment: wait a sec, I have to check

Comment: have you tried to remove `where size IN(".$size_list .")` from query?

Comment: It will list all products if I do so! It is needed to restrict records to which we want through `$size_list`, but I need all available sizes for each product

Comment: so if you give sizes = (1, 2) you want to get records for which are exist size 1 or 2, but you want to get all sizes for this records?

Comment: yes, this is the correct word. It would be appreciated if you help me accomplish this

Comment: would you please help me on this?

Comment: changed query, try that

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll give it a try and report here soon.